# In Spring Data JPA using Schema Multi Tenant, how to join with other schema although the same entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using schema-based multitenancy in Spring Data JPA.

```
properties.put("hibernate.multiTenancy", MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
```

The table structure of the "Common" schema and the "A" schema is the same.
These two schemas are multi-tenant structures that use the same entity.
There's an entry called User in "A" schema and "Common" schema.
How do I join these two entities?

I want to create a query like this. (The schema is currently selected as A by Tenant setting.)

```
select u.* from user u left join common.user u2 on u.common_id = u2.id;
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Long commonId; // right?
}
```

Should I use native query without using JPQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with JPA.

Btw. JPA doesn't know multitenancy that's a Hibernate feature.